# Multivariable optimization - how to parametrize a boundary?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, parametric

> A metal plate has the shape of the region $x^2 + y^2 \leq  1$. The plate is heated so that the temperature at any point $(x,y)$ on it is indicated by
>
> $$T(x,y) = 2x^2 + y^2 - y + 3$$
>
> Find the hottest and coldest points on the plate and the temperature at each of these points. (Hint: Parametrize the boundary of the plate in order to find any critical points there.)

I know how to do the actual optimization part of this problem. I already found a critical point at (0,0.5) by setting the first partial derivatives equal to 0. My problem is, how do I parametrize the boundary to find the other ones? I've seen solutions where they used cos(t) and sin(t) - where and how did they know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

We parametrize $x=\sin t, y=\cos t$  (although it works if we switch $x$ and $y$ as well). We obtain: $$2\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t-\cos t+3.$$Take the derivative and solve: $$\sin t(2\cos t+1)=0.$$

**Edit**
An important part I left out is that $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$. We choose this time interval because it traverses the circle exactly once.

Comment: Yes, I understand that we can use cos(t) and sin(t). However, I do not understand why? Where do we get that formula or assumption? Why can't we use any arbitrary function of t?

Comment: Well we wish to parametrize the circle the whole way around. I think maybe the best way to see why we choose this parametrization is to note that  it satisfies your boundary $x^2+y^2=1$  (think Pythagorean identity). parametrizations are not unique so it is in our interest to pick one that is simple. For example, $\sin 2t$ and $\cos 2t$ would also satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$ but in the same time interval this would traverse twice the distance as our initial parametrization in the same time.